# API for find smart-contract deployed which chain?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, external-api, the-graph

Is there any API which gives me details that project smart-contract deployed on which chain via its smart-contract address?
e.g. How to know whether it deployed in polygon, avalanche, ethereum?

If is there any way to discover it or is there any graph query to fetch contract data?
It is possible to create API via graph protocol?